# Folland Lemma 8.25

Tags: fourier-transform, change-of-variable

Folland claims in Lemma 8.25

> If $f, g \in L^1(\mathbf{R}^d)$, then $\int f \hat g = \int \hat f g$.

Note that by the $\hat\cdot$ notation, Folland means the Fourier transform.

My question is why is this true? The proof (in Folland) appears to be just an application of Fubini Theorem. But why is it obvious that the integrand: 
$$
f(x) g(\theta) e^{-2\pi i \langle x, \theta \rangle} 
$$
is in $L^1(\mathbf{R}^d \times \mathbf{R}^d)$ if $f, g \in L^1(\mathbf{R}^d)$?

Comment: Which book by Folland?

Comment: Real Analysis - Modern Techniques and Their Applications

Comment: Why is it not obvious, what are you worried about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that $|f \widehat{g}| \leq |f| {\cdot} |\widehat{g}|_\infty \leq |f| {\cdot} \|g\|_{L^1}$ and similiar $|g\widehat{f}| \leq |g| \|f\|_{L^1}$. Thus, both integrals exist (in the sense of Lebesgue-integrals as usual). Now, observe that $|f(x) g(\theta) e^{- 2\pi \mathrm{i}\langle x, \theta \rangle}| \leq |f(x) g(\theta)|$. And because of the theorem of Fubini (resp. Tonelli), we know that $\int \int |f(x)| {\cdot} |g(\theta)| \, \rm{d}x \, \rm{d} \theta =\|f\|_{L^1} \|g\|_{L^1} < \infty$, i.e. your function is integrable.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that this a complete argument, can you look at mine?

Comment: I agree with everything up until the "And because of the theorem of Fubini...". Is that really what Fubini Theorem says? It looks like you're assuming you can apply Fubini, and applying it and then saying that the function is integrable.

Comment: @DrewBrady looks fine to me, maybe you want to write out Fubini and Tonelli

Comment: I see. So I'm looking at the statement of Fubini here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem. So the point is that in the notation of Wiki, $|f(x, y)| = |\hat f(x) g(y)|$, and we can pull out the $g(y)$ when evaluating the inner integral. This gives the finiteness result that p4sch refers to, THEN you 'apply Fubini-Tonelli' by saying because this integral is finite so to is the reverse of integration order, and furthermore (by the Fubini-Tonelli Thm) their values are the same.

Comment: Edit in other words, p4sch's reasoning, I believe is correct, though he does not actually apply Fubini Tonelli ever (but after reading his proof, we may now apply Fubini Tonelli, and swap integration order, giving the result)

Comment: Depending on your book/source, the theorem of Fubini-Tonelli makes two statements: 1.) If the function is non-negative, the theorem is true. This is sometimes called the theorem of Tonelli, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem_for_non-negative_functions). Of course, the absolute value of a function is always non-negative. Thus, we can apply Fubini-Tonelli on $|f(x) g(\theta)|$ and get that this function is integrable. 2.) The theorem is true, if the function is integrable. Because of 1.), we can now apply 2.)

Comment: @DrewBrady there is no integration of $|\hat f(x) g(y)|$, so you plugged in the wrong $f(x,y)$

Comment: Ah I see. p4sch, you are using the Tonelli theorem. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do this as follows:

First, you observe that if $E_1$ and $E_2$ are measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$, then $E_1 \times E_2$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d$. From which you conclude that if $f$ and $g$ are measurable on $\mathbb{R}^d$ then $H(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d$, then you're allowed to use Fubini's theorem because $H$ is measurable and you could estimate the integral using the $L^1$ norms of $f$ and $g$ resepectively to conclude that $H \in L^1( \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d) $.

Apply this reasoning to your problem.